# Websphere BASE version - Manage endpoint security configurations

Tags: security, ssl-certificate, websphere, key-management

I need to set-up the Endpoint security configuration ( [Reference - This IBM Doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/usec_sslsecendptcom.html) )

When I do Admin Console -> Security -> SSL certificate and key management -> Manage endpoint security configurations

According to the IBM doc, I should be seeing Inboind / Outbound links, but I don't see any links that I can set up for certificate related info.

This is what I should see

[image: Local Topology - with links]

This is what I actually see

[image: Empty Local Settings]

Can someone let me know, what is missing on my server set-up or profile?

Comment: Are there any errors in the logs?   One reason I can think of why that panel would be blank is if there is some kind of error parsing the security.xml file.  One other reason would be if there are no sslConfigGroups in the security.xml file.

Comment: No errors in the logs.  Also, for the teammate for whom it works, he doesn't have sslConfigGroups in the security.xml file either.

Answer (score 0):

The document is for WebSphere Application Server **Network Deployment**, not BASE edition.  This particular admin section is used to manage certificates used *between* the components within the cell.  Base does not offer cells, nodes, clusters, ...